# General way to add a save capability to a class in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, pickle, metaclass

I recently hit on the idea of using some form of metaprogramming to replace the (admittedly limit) boilerplate code needed to persist and then load objects using pickle. So you'd get something like

```
class MyClass(object):
    # Something to add save-ability (maybe a decorator or metaclass)...
    # More code...

my_instance = MyClass('/path/to/persistent_file')
my_instance.do_some_stuff()
my_instance.save()
my_instance._do_some_more_stuff()
my_instance.save()
```

I attemped to accomplish this by using a metaclass. Unfortunately it did not turn out as well as I had hoped. The __init__ methods became complicated because this happens:

1. The user calls MyClass(path, other_args) to either open an existing persistent instance or, if none exists at *path*, create a new one
2. The system finds a file at *path* and calls pickle.load() to read it
3. pickle.load() makes another call to MyClass.__init__ to build the object based on what it read from disk

MyClass.__init__'s ability to tell #1 from #3 is basically a hack in my implementation. Is there a clean way to do this (whether using metaclasses, decorators, or whatever)?

EDIT: @roippi asked, "It sounds like you're trying to reimplement shelve, no?" Yes, this exercise started as an effort to reimplement shelve, but allowing arbitrary keys, which is basically what my SyncPickleDict is. Then I found myself wanting to generalize it. I've fixed the example to use non-string keys to make this a little clearer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import pickle
import os
import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

class SyncPickleParent(object):
    def __init__ (self, filepath, *args, **kwargs):
        print "here and self is", self
        self.__filepath = filepath
        super(SyncPickleParent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def sync_pickle(self):
        with open(self.__filepath, "w") as ofile:
            pickle.dump(self, ofile)


class SyncPickle(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        return super(SyncPickle, meta).__new__(meta, name, (SyncPickleParent,)+bases, dct)

    def __call__(cls, filepath, force_init=False, force_overwrite=False, *args, **kwds):
        if force_init:
            return type.__call__(cls, filepath, *args, **kwds)
        if not force_overwrite:
            try:
                with open(filepath) as ifile:
                    red = pickle.load(ifile)
                    red._SyncPickleParent__filepath = filepath
                    return red
            except IOError as ioe:
                pass
        result = type.__call__(cls, filepath, *args, **kwds)
        result.sync_pickle() # Check that file is writable
        return result


class SyncPickleDict(OrderedDict):
    __metaclass__ = SyncPickle

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "in init; args={}; kwargs={}".format(args, kwargs)
        super(SyncPickleDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __reduce__(self):
        # Yuck. The tuple output by __reduce__ has to have two bogus
        # arguments
        return (self.__class__, ("dummy", True, False, tuple(self.items())))


if "__main__" == __name__:
    spd = SyncPickleDict(os.path.expanduser("~/tmp/bar.dat"))
    spd[(1,2,3)] = 'foobar'
    spd['access_count'] = spd.get('access_count', 0) + 1
    spd[datetime.datetime.now()] = "A new key every time"
    spd.sync_pickle()
    print "\n".join(map(str, spd.iteritems()))
```

Comment: This might be suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @aIKid, I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. I don't know which site is the better fit, but it seems to be a moot point for me since thus far I haven't found a way for non-moderators to move stuff between sites.

Comment: I would ask "why use metaclasses?" here.  It seems that regular subclassing would do the job.

Comment: I'm using metaclasses to intercept that call to the actual class's \_\_init__ method and say, "if there's a file at _filepath_, just load it instead of doing the regular \_\_init__." I don't want to require the that logic to have to be reproduces in every class that uses this functionality. OTOH the issue is posted here because the result of doing it this way is not so good. I guess I could say that classes using sync_pickle feature can't have an \_\_init__ method but should instead provide a method that SyncPickle will call if it finds no file at _filepath_. Is that the best way?

Comment: It is possible to create instances without calling their `__init__()`: try `SomeClass.__new__(SomeClass)`.